# How do I avoid type lost?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
enum Media {
  case image
  case video
}

struct UploadManager {

  static func upload(mediaType: Media, data: AnyObject, completion: Response -> Void) {
    switch mediaType {
    case .image:
        uploadImage(data as? UIImage, completion: completion)
    case .video:
        uploadVideo(data as? NSURL, completion: completion)
    }
  }

  static func uploadImage(image: UIImage, completion: Response -> Void ) {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    let options = ["resourcetype": "image"]
    //API call
  }

  static func uploadVideo(filePath: NSURL, completion: Response -> Void ) {
    let options = ["resourcetype": "video"]
    //API call

  }
}
```

Sample call  will be:

```
UploadManager.upload(.image, data: data, completion: {

})
```

Here Im making request to UploadManager with .image type and data. My concern is image and data are mutual exclusive and prone to error. Say, I passed .image instead of .video and While downcasting it will lead to crash. Any way to handle this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can embed data in your enum. For example:

```
enum Media {
  case Image(image: UIImage)
  case Video(url: NSURL)
}
```

And you can extract them in the `match-case`:

```
static func upload(media: Media, completion: Response -> Void) {
    switch media {
    case .Image(let image):
        uploadImage(image, completion: completion)
    case .Video(let url):
        uploadVideo(url, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Then, you can call this method like this:

```
let image = UIImage()
UploadManager.upload(.Image(image)) { response in
    print("Upload complete!")
}
```